# django reverse query

Tags: python, django, orm

Am trying to query from parent to child and with a single query being able to have the child results in parent. In my example, am trying to do a relation between i18n tables in which I want to include the row from the child table in a single hit.

models.py

```
class main(models.Model):
    slug       = models.SlugField()
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    site       = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

class main_i18n(models.Model):
    main        = models.ForeignKey(main)
    language    = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LANGUAGES)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("language", "main"))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I tried the following to query

```
a=main.objects.filter(is_active=True, main_i18n__language='en')
```

and the relation its done perfectly, here is what I saw when tried to print the query

```
>>> a.query.__str__()
'SELECT `category_main`.`id`, `category_main`.`slug`, `category_main`.`is_active`, `category_main`.`site_id` FROM `category_main` INNER JOIN `category_main_i18n` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_main_i18n`.`main_id`) WHERE (`category_main_i18n`.`language` = en  AND `category_main`.`is_active` = True )'
```

As you see from the query, it does the join correctly but the column names is not included in the select statement. I cannot access the main_i18n data when trying to do a for loop.

sorry for my lousy english and hope i can find help,

Best wishes,

**---- EDIT:**

below is the template am currently using, ultimately I would really like to create a single query and do regrouping based to list the data in my view.

```
    <table class="homepage-listing">
        <tr>
            <td>
{#                {% regroup list by main as rg_main %}#}
                {% for obj in main %}
{#                    {% if obj.grouper != None %}#}
                    <div class="listing-block">
                            <a href="#" ><h3>{{ obj }}</h3></a>
                            <ul>
                                {% for s in obj.list %}
                                    <li>{{ s.list_i18n_set.get }} </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                    </div>
{#                    {% endif %}#}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

--- EDIT:

I had to use the extra functions to to build a single query for that purpose. I started with it but getting a bit complicated, am trying to make sure the columns not hardcoded in the queries and the joins are correct. Can anyone tell me if there is a better way to write the query?

```
    dict = Main.objects.extra(
    select=
    {
        'main_title' : '%s.%s' % (MainI18n._meta.db_table, MainI18n._meta.get_field('title').verbose_name),
        'list_title' : '%s.%s' % (ListI18n._meta.db_table, ListI18n._meta.get_field('title').verbose_name),
    },
    tables=[
            '%s' % (MainI18n._meta.db_table),
            '%s' % (List._meta.db_table),
            '%s' % (ListI18n._meta.db_table),
    ],
    where=[
            '%s.%s=%s.%s' % (MainI18n._meta.db_table, 'main_id', Main._meta.db_table, 'id'),
            '%s.main_id=%s.id' % (List._meta.db_table, Main._meta.db_table),
            '%s.list_id=%s.id' % (ListI18n._meta.db_table, List._meta.db_table),
            'category_listi18n.language="%s"' % (request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    ]).select_related().filter(maini18n__language=request.LANGUAGE_CODE )
```

Comment: Could you show the loop your are using? As far as i understand select_related saves an extra db query when you call an attribute on your related model but the data should nonetheless be retrievable even without a select_related.

Comment: select_related only works "forward". Since the lookup is not on the model the fk is defined, select_related will not pull the data in the db hit.

Comment: I just updated the post with the template code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query `MainI18N` instead:

```
MainI18N.objects.filter(main__is_active=True, language='en').select_related('main')
```

EDIT: You can wrap this in a custom queryset method. The quick solution (which doesn't allow you to further filter the QuerySet) would look something like this:

```
class MainQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def translate(self, lang):
       for obj in MainI18N.filter(language=lang, main__in=self).select_related('main'):
           main = obj.main
           main.i18n = obj
           yield main
```

Comment: am trying to avoid this approach because then my application logic will be built based on querying the translation tables almost all the time. Anything else you can recommend for my case?

Comment: even if you have suggestions for changes to the model

Comment: You could wrap this in a custom QuerySet method for `Main` (I'll edit my answer). If all else fails, you can still use `QuerySet.extra()`.

Comment: @emullbreh: I tried almost all approaches and I think extra is the most powerful and flexible for creating single complex query with all my results. I just updated my question the query, maybe you can help me simplify it if you happen to know any technique.. appreciated

Answer (score 2):

When you use a foreign key you need to access that data through the RelatedManager. In your case you would access data in the main_i18n from the main like:

```
>>> a=main.objects.get(id=1)
>>> i18n = a.main_i18n_set.get()
>>> i18n.language
u'en'
```

or if you need to operate on multiple objects:

```
a = main.objects.filter(is_active=True, main_i18n__language='en')
for obj in a:
  i18n = obj.main_i18n_set.get()
  print i18n.language
```

which would of course print 'en' for each object return by the filter.

Comment: Additionally, you can use a.main_i18n_set.all() to get all instances of the related model.

Comment: Good point. The RelatedManager acts much like the other managers, so you can run filter, all, get, etc. on the main_i18n_set.

Comment: @chris, thanks for the response, what you mentioned works. But if I pass "a" to the template i will have to hit the database for the i18n table as many as there is records in "a". Any idea how i can avoid this situation?

Comment: That is when you use [select_related](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: I should give you useage on that: a=main.objects.filter(is_active=True, main_i18n__language='en').select_related(depth=1) # depth essentially is how many foreign keys deep the select will go.

Comment: @Chris, I tried to use a.main_i18n_set.get() but when using filters you cannot use a.main_i18n_set.get() only when "a" is retrieved using get.

Comment: When you use filter, it returns a list of objects, so 'a' is a list, so you'll want to use a for loop: for obj in a: i18n = obj.main_i18n_set.get()